# Add multiple CIDR to SourceAddressPrefix using powershell to Azure NSG rule

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-nsg

I'm trying to add multiple CIDR to the SourceAddressPrefix when creating a NSG rule in Azure using powershell. I get the error message when running the Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup so it accepts the value when creating the rule using New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig. Anyone knows how to solve it? 
Note: Yes I know that I can create multiple rules but I want to avoid that if possible.

Using the portal this works fine but using Powershell I get error message.

Attempt 1:

```
 $rule3 = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "In-SandNet-Vnet-Any-Any" `
-Access Allow -Protocol *  -Direction Inbound -Priority 1000 -SourceAddressPrefix {"10.0.0.0/8","192.168.0.0/16"} `
 -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix VirtualNetwork  -DestinationPortRange * 

$nsg.SecurityRules.Add($rule3)

Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
```

Error message:

```
xxx has invalid Address prefix. Value provided: "10.0.0.0/8","192.168.0.0/16"
```

Attempt 2:

```
$rule3 = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "In-SandNet-Vnet-Any-Any" `
    -Access Allow -Protocol *  -Direction Inbound -Priority 1000 -SourceAddressPrefix "10.0.0.0/8,192.168.0.0/16" `
     -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix VirtualNetwork  -DestinationPortRange * 

$nsg.SecurityRules.Add($rule3)


Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
```

Error message (same error message):

```
xxx has invalid Address prefix. Value provided: "10.0.0.0/8","192.168.0.0/16"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig` command expects a `String[]` for `SourceAddressPrefix` parameter. *([Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/new-aznetworksecurityruleconfig?view=azps-3.5.0))*

So the following should work:

`@("10.0.0.0/8", "192.168.0.0/16")`

Comment: I was so close but no cigar for me.. Thank you. That solved it.